# Can I say "thank you for having us" before the end of a visit?

Tags: phrase-usage, tense, past-tense

A few years ago I was visiting a friend's home, and since I'm always painfully polite, I wanted to thank his mother for being willing to have a group of boys in her home for the weekend.

So when I met her the first thing I said was, "*Thank you for having us.*" to which the pretentious woman replied, "*I haven't had you yet, have I?*"

Now apart from the obvious ambiguity in her response I thought, *surely "*having us*" is present continuous tense*, meaning that it was technically correct to use this phrase mid-visit even though it's generally used in an implied past tense once you've already been hosted and thanking someone for their hospitality.

Clearly, I was traumatised by this lady. So please, tell me I was right and that she was rude.

Comment: It's fine. Same as saying *Thank you for inviting me to dinner* as you sit down to eat at a friend's table. The pretentious woman's reply *I haven't had you yet, have I?*  is a weak pun / facetious joke. Ignore it, or smile politely.

Comment: Not your fault, man - you were polite, and grammatically and semantically correct. Who is right doesn't matter.

Comment: I had 'thank you for having me' drilled into me by my parents and parroted it out on leaving any visit or stay. Depending on my age, I would either have just blinked, or appreciated the humour, should a friend's mother have replied as this one did.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the others have mentioned, that was a terrible joke cracked by her. However if you'd like to use the same phrase in the future, say "**Thank you for having us over**" instead.